# Use dnx to call test class within namespace subfolder

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, xunit

Using dnx I want to execute a test class with the following command:

```
dnx test -method TestNamespace.TestClassName
```

However, my namespace is called "TestNameSpace.Tests" since the test methods are located in the tests folder and so I am a bit confused as to how I would call it? I tried something like this but it didn't work...

```
dnx test -class "TestNamespace.Tests".TestClass
```

... as it probably tries to run it as a method:

```
dnx test -method TestNamespace.TestClassName.TestMethodName
```

Probably an easy one, any takers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders have nothing to do with namespaces. The namespace is at the top of your `cs` file. Take that namespace, the class name, and the method name. Put them together and that's what you pass to `-method`.

Ex:

```
namespace Foo.Tests 
{
    public class BarClass 
    {
        [Fact]
        public void BazTest() 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Args:

`dnx test -method Foo.Tests.BarClass.BazTest`